# How to consume as much sodium as possible?

Tags: sodium

I've recently been diagnosed with postural hypotension. When I stand I get very light headed and dizzy. I've seen several doctors who have struggled to find the cause or find a treatment that works. My latest doctor just yesterday put me on an experimental treatment that's not as easy to execute as it might seem:

**Consume as much salt as possible.**

We're talking about 5x the daily recommended intake, or more. The doctor suggested I eat at least 5 cubes of chicken flavored bouillon dissolved in hot water every day. That's 2480 mg of sodium (104% recommended daily sodium intake), times 5. As you might imagine, this isn't very pleasant. I'd like to find some other way of consuming this much sodium, and doing so efficiently.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Processed Foods.